# Keras embedding layer: indices[4,0] = 179819 is not in [0, 8984)

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to train a simple movie recommendation system using the latest-small movie lens dataset, but I keep getting an error saying that:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\AI\Python projects\anotherone.py", line 48, in <module>
    history = model.fit([train.userId,train.movieId], train.rating,epochs=10, verbose=1)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 780, in fit
    steps_name='steps_per_epoch')
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_arrays.py", line 363, in model_iteration
    batch_outs = f(ins_batch)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py", line 3292, in _call_
    run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1458, in _call_
    run_metadata_ptr)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: indices[4,0] = 179819 is not in [0, 8984)
     [[{{node Movie-Embedding/embedding_lookup}}]]
```

Code:

```
#  importing libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import warnings
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Embedding, Flatten, Dot, Dense, concatenate
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
# ignoring warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

# importing our data
df = pd.read_csv('D:/AI/Data sets/ml-latest-small/ratings.csv')
train, test = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

#  extracting the unique number of users and movies
n_users = len(df.userId.unique())
n_movies = len(df.movieId.unique())


# creating the embedding
movie_input = Input(shape=[1], name="Movie-Input")
movie_embedding = Embedding(n_movies+1, 5, name="Movie-Embedding")(movie_input)
movie_vec  =  Flatten(name="Flatten-Movie")(movie_embedding)

user_input = Input(shape=[1], name = "User-Input")
user_embedding = Embedding(n_users+1, 5, name="User-Embedding")(user_input)
user_vec = Flatten(name="Flatten-user")(user_embedding)

# concatinating the features
concat = concatenate([movie_vec,user_vec])

# creating our model
layer1 = Dense(128,activation="relu")(concat)
layer2 = Dense(32,activation="relu")(layer1)
outputLayer = Dense(1)(layer2)
model = Model([user_input,movie_input],outputLayer)
model.compile('adam','mean_squared_error')

#  tranning the model
if os.path.exists('multiParam.h5'):
    model = load_model('multiParam.h5')
else:
    history = model.fit([train.userId,train.movieId], train.rating,epochs=10, verbose=1)
    model.save('multiParam.h5')
    plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
    plt.xlabel("Epochs")
    plt.ylabel("Training Error")

# testing the model
print(model.evaluate([test.userId, test.movieId], test.rating))

# running some predictions
predictions = model.predict([test.userId.head(10), test.movieId.head(10)])
[print(predictions[i], test.rating.iloc[i]) for i in range(0,10)]
```

I'm still new to machine learning, but from the research I understood, I need to provide the number of unique values +1 to the embedding layer, which I'm doing but It's still not working, any help can be appreciated, thank you :)

Comment: Its not the number of unique values, its the maximum index + 1

Answer (score 0):

You should try Label encoding for both movieId and userId in order to make them sequential starting from zero :

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
user_enc = LabelEncoder()
df['user'] = user_enc.fit_transform(df['userId'].values)
n_users = df['user'].nunique()
item_enc = LabelEncoder()
df['movie'] = item_enc.fit_transform(df['movieId'].values)
n_movies = df['movie'].nunique()
```